# how to convert image captured with camera to base64 with flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

I want to convert image captured with camera to base64 but it seems am converting the image path and not the image itself, please help me.

```
File file;
final picker = ImagePicker();
void _choose() async {
  final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
  file = File(pickedFile.path);
  if (file != null) {
    setState(() {
      base64Encode(file.readAsBytesSync());
      print(base64Encode(Image.file(file));
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong:

```
print(base64Encode(Image.file(file));
```

Right:

```
print(base64Encode(file.readAsBytesSync()));
```

Comment: Could you provide more details on what your code does?